# what is the actual use of xml and json in java web service?

Tags: java, rest

i am new to java and i am confuse why java Restful webservice always show output in xml/json?what is the actual uses of xml and json?

can we use xml/json file as a database for an application?

Answer (score 2):

XML and JSON are *not* databases; they are message formats.

You can certainly persist either XML or JSON in SQL or NoSQL databases as CLOBs or documents, respectively.

Web services accept HTTP requests - GETs, POSTs, etc.

SOAP web services use SOAP XML to define their request/response message formats.

REST services usually use straight HTTP.  Browsers support JSON, so it's natural to exchange it with REST services.

Answer (score 1):

Restfull web services client and server doesn't rely on chosen language that's why you need a universal "language" in order to be understood by everyone.

XML and JSON are used to [marshall/unmarshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) data on either client and server side most of the time JSON is used for Restull web services.

For your question

> can we use xml/json file as a database for an application?

I would say yes but it's not the best way for data querying you should consider SQL or NoSQL database depending on your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind web services is to expose some kind of functionality to a broad variety of possible clients - web sites, mobile applications, desktop applications, etc. They use (in most of the cases) a standard web communication protocol - HTTP, which is text based. So we have a problem - we have Java objects in the backend, that need to be propagated to the clients. In order to transport them they have to have a unified textual representation. Here is where XML and JSON prove to be most useful.

Both XML and JSON are ways to present data in a text format. They are commonly called message formats, data interchange formats, etc. They contain a set of rules that define how to present structured data in a concise way, making it possible to transfer it around.

Web services are not forced to use XML or JSON. It's just that those are the most mature and widely used technologies at the current time.

Both XML and JSON define how data should be presented as text, but they don't contain any persistence capabilities, meaning, they can't be used as databases. They can be stored as text in databases or files, but this depends on the concrete situation and should not be generalised.